# PHP - Set first array's values to second array's iterations

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, binary

I'm trying to make one array set to the iterations of another array. I'm working on a hash algorithm that takes in a user value of the order they want the array. It takes their code and breaks it down into 40 blocks of binary to be converted into hexadecimal. So far I'm able to change the iteration order, but it only takes the last value of the first array and sets as the value for each iteration of the second array.

The first array looks like this (Showing only 10 of the 40 to save space):

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0111
    [1] => 1000
    [2] => 0110
    [3] => 0010
    [4] => 0011
    [5] => 0001
    [6] => 0011
    [7] => 0010
    [8] => 0011
    [9] => 0101
)
```

The second one is like this:

```
Array
(
    [3] => 0101
    [2] => 0101
    [1] => 0101
    [6] => 0101
    [5] => 0101
    [4] => 0101
    [9] => 0101
    [8] => 0101
    [7] => 0101
    [0] => 0101
)
```

And here is the PHP code:

```
$arrayDump = $test->binarySplit($name);

$ordered = array();
$orderKey = array(3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4, 9, 8, 7, 12, 11, 10, 15, 14, 13, 18, 17, 16, 21, 20, 19, 24, 23, 22, 27, 26, 25, 30, 29, 28, 33, 32, 31, 36, 35, 34, 39, 38, 37, 0);

foreach ($orderKey as $key) {
    for ($i = $key; $i < count($arrayDump); $i++) {
        $ordered[$key] = $arrayDump[$i];
    }

}
```

The class call above isn't too important for this problem that I can tell. The `$arrayDump` is the first array; `$ordered` is the second. As you can tell, the second array changes the iteration to be what I want, but it only contains the last value from the first array. I threw it through a loop to try and get each value, but I'm at a loss. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the second loop, try this:

```
foreach ($orderKey as $key => $value) {
    $ordered[$key] = $arrayDump[$value];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was obsessed with the iteration order, I didn't think about letting the order stay the same and reordering the values. I appreciate your help as a second mind to look at it.